# Angular - 'Listen' on @ViewChild changes

Tags: angular

How can be a function like `onElChanged` be implemented, so that this functions gets executed each time properties of `<div #plot id="plot-container"></div>` changed?

***component.html***

```
<div #plot id="plot-container"></div>
```

***component.ts***

```
@ViewChild('plot') el: ElementRef;

onElChanged(){
  console.log(this.el.nativeElement.clientWidth);
}
```

Comment: For the specific example given the ResizeObserver can be used to process element size changes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resize_Observer_API

Answer (score 24):

Though not a solution that uses @ViewChild decorator, **you can use the very similar `@ViewChildren` decorator to subscribe to changes** despite your particular observed subject being a non-list-like singular element.

You can use the `first` (or `last`) `QueryList` member to obtain the `ElementRef` value - ignoring most of the list-specific parts of the `QueryList` interface - which is the quick and dirty approach I use below. *However, it is probably recommended to handle a singular element iteratively as a list of length 1 to stick with the typical `@ViewChildren` paradigm and create more generically useful methods and services.*

```
@ViewChildren('plot', {read: ElementRef}) el: QueryList<ElementRef>;

/**
 * Listen within this component
 */
private listenForPlotChanges() {
    this.el.changes.subscribe(
        (next: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
            console.log('listenForPlotChanges next:', next);

            const plot = next.first.nativeElement;
            console.log('listentForPlotChanges plot:', plot);
         }
    );
}
```

Or an example from a listener that exists outside a component (with special consideration for illustrating an update to the element via `Renderer2`)...

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable, QueryList, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ISubscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

/**
 * Listen and update with renderer as a service outside a component
 *
 * Usage:
 *  @ViewChildren('yourElement', {read: ElementRef}) el: QueryList<ElementRef>;
 *
 *  constructor(listener: ListenerService) {}
 *
 *  ngAfterViewInit() {
 *    this.listener.listenForPlotChanges(this.el);
 *  }
 */
@Injectable()
export class ListenerService {

private renderer: Renderer2;

constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
}

listenForPlotChanges(elementQueryList: QueryList<ElementRef>): ISubscription {

    const resolveNext = (next) => {
            console.log('listenForPlotChanges next:', next);

            const plot = next.first.nativeElement;
            console.log('listentForPlotChanges plot:', plot);

            this.renderer.addClass(plot, 'twist');
    }

    return elementQueryList.changes.subscribe(
        (next: QueryList<ElementRef>) => {
            resolveNext(next);
        }
    }
}
```

I've used my suggested approach in Angular version `^5.2.1` and have not verified for other versions of Angular including the latest.

Comment: Nice but you have a typo QuerList -> QueryList

Answer (score 8):

You could create a directive that uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen to attribute changes in the DOM for your specific element.

**dom-change.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[domChange]'
})
export class DomChangeDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private changes: MutationObserver;

  @Output()
  public domChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    this.changes = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
        mutations.forEach((mutation: MutationRecord) => this.domChange.emit(mutation));
      }
    );

    this.changes.observe(element, {
      attributes: true
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.changes.disconnect();
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div id="plot-container" (domChange)="onDomChange($event)"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
onDomChange($event: Event): void {
    console.log($event);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is easier and will listen for changes

```
@ViewChildren('plot', {read: ElementRef}) el: QueryList<ElementRef>

ngDoCheck(){
    let plotElement = this.el
    if(plotElement){
      console.log(plotElement)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That i know of, there is no way to listen for property changes of an element (for this scenario). Though there might be some other library that can achieve this. This might be of some help though:

```
this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener(typeOfEvent);
```

Comment: Is there any `typeOfEvent` which fires if css properties changed?

Comment: @d4rty you might implement your own solution using `new CustomEvent('cssChanged')` and dispatch your customEvent on any css change you apply.

Answer (score 0):

TS

```
@ViewChildren("content") content!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

isVisible: boolean = false;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content.changes.subscribe(() => {
        // Code
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible" #content>
```