# How to subscribe to changes of ElementRef.nativeElement property?

Tags: angular, rxjs

## The problem

I am trying to figure out the best way to detect changes in UI element width, in order to assign the width into google chart. Google chart doesn't support width in % and exact width needs to be assigned to its options dataset.

Running on Angular 4

## My approach

```javascript
@ViewChild('portlet') public portlet: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() { // same issue if used in ngOnInit()
   this.widthObservable = new BehaviorSubject<number>
      (this.portlet.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
   this.widthObservable.asObservable().subscribe(e => {
      console.log('Width changed', e);  // only fires once for e=0 
      // ...
      // set google chart dataset width property
      // chart.redraw();
   });
   ...
}
```

I'm only ever getting 1 console log message `Width changed 0`. When I set breakpoint anywhere in the code (after UI initialization) I can see the `this.portlet.nativeElement.offsetWidth` has non-zero value. This is expected, because the UI component renders, however I don't understand why the observable doesn't fire up again.

## Questions

- Is this the best approach?
- Why is my observable only firing once?

Comment: is it not working?

Comment: As described in my original post - it only ever fires once, even though I can see the offsetWidth has non-0 value after the UI draws (verified in unrelated breakpoints)

Comment: Why are you defining behaviour subject inside life cycle hook?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! Where else should it be defined? The viewchild nativeElement.offsetWidth seems to only become available at certain point in the component lifecycle. Is there a better way to hook into it?

Comment: try to define behaviour subject outside ngAfterviewInit and us ngOninit instead of ngAfterview Init

Comment: Why would one lifecycle hook be different from another when it comes to setting up observables on unrelated variable? (btw, I tried that before posting here)

Comment: did that worked?

Comment: No it doesn't :D Like I said, I had tried beforehand. Why in the world would subscription in ngOnInit be different from ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: is it possible to add your code on stackblitz.com

Comment: jmmygoggle's answer in here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375156/angular-listen-on-viewchild-changes