# Angular. Wait for viewchildren to be updated

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to update component's property "rows" that is used by component's template via *ngFor*:

```
    ngFor="let row of rows"
... render child components
```

Child components are collected by

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
```

My current pseudo code (that updates *rows* and should wait for *children*) looks like that:

```
fooMethod(): void {
  rows = ...increase rows count
  // wait here for children to be updated!
  for child of children {
      // process child 
   }
}
```

*Children* are updated only after fooMethod is executed at present

The problem is I have to wait for *children* to be populated after *rows* property is updated to work further with *children: QueryList*.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check the following solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375156/angular-listen-on-viewchild-changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do your code inside viewchildren like :-

```
@ViewChildren(ChildComponent) 
set children(components: QueryList<ChildComponent) {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it may work for me, but may be you will suggest something more usefull - I've updated my question with code sample.

Comment: it;s the most proper way, you can call a method inside there to do the job.