# Angular: ngForm created event

Tags: angular

is there any way how to be notified, that ngForm has been created?

I have in template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="itemChanged$ | async as item">
      <form
        #editForm="ngForm"
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(item)"
        autocomplete="off"
        class="mt-20">
    ...
```

and in ts:

```
@ViewChild('editForm') editForm?: NgForm;
    
itemChanged$ = this.service.itemChanged$.pipe(
    map(item => {...})
)
```

But, the problem is that editForm is undefined in OnInit and also in AfterInit.
The editForm is created when itemChanged$ occured, and item is not null.

So, how can I catch that editForm is created? I would like to do some more actions with the form after that.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - 'Listen' on @ViewChild changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375156/angular-listen-on-viewchild-changes)

Comment: I do not think so. ListenerService did not work for me. MutationObserver and ngChange works but I would say its quite overhead - they are "fired" on every form change. I hoped there will be some possibility just handle one event fired when form is created.